# Insert Into Won't Copy Data "Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'"

Tags: mysql, error-handling, primary-key, sql-insert

All I'm trying to do is use the code below to copy the data from the 'drive' column in the 'vehicle' table to the 'vehicleDrive' column in the 'vehicleDrive' table. But I get an error saying "Duplicate entry for '0' for key 'PRIMARY'".

There is a primary key on both tables with a non-unique id of 0. But it's not letting me change them. How do I fix that?

```
insert into vehicleDrive (vehicleDrive) (
select distinct(drive) from vehicle);
```

Answer (score 0):

This beacuse you don't have an auto increment primary key ...(so then insert the second row the primary key is set to 0 for the second time and you get the error)

then try somethings like this  in your table

```
CREATE TABLE `your_table` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 ......
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```